# ImageMagick ignores my alpha channel and lowers the bit depth

Tags: image-processing, imagemagick, transparency

Here's the image I'm working on:

[image]

Here's the MS_DOS command line:

convert "IM_Effect_Smoke_problem.png" -background transparent -crop 64x64+0+64! "IM_Effect_Smoke_problem_crop.png"

The problem is that ImageMagick reduces the color depth to 8 bits and ignores or destroys the alpha channel.

Can anyone tell me how to fix this? Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

Testing the command with ImageMagick 6.6.9-7, on Ubuntu, preserves the alpha channel. Maybe there the issue is with the version of ImageMagick you're using if you're sure the alpha channel is removed.

Comment: I have ImageMagick-6.7.6-9-Q16-windows-dll installed on both my Vista and Windows 7 machines, and get the same results on both.

Comment: Never mind. The problem was with XnView not displaying/detecting the image properly. Paint.Net and Chrome both display the image properly.